# Breakpoint in SSIS script task which is inside a ForEach Loop

Tags: ssis, task, breakpoints

I have an SSIS package which has got a foreach loop. inside the foreach loop I have a script task. I have put breakpoint in that script task, which gets hit but the problem is, it only gets hit on the first iteration. so if F10 or F5 it does not break again on the second iteration.

how can i make it break each time on the same point on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a expected behaviour of SSIS, as stated in Books Online:

***"If a Script task is part of a Foreach Loop or For Loop container, the debugger ignores breakpoints in the Script task after the first iteration of the loop."***

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137625.aspx

You can try to work around it with the following alternatives:

- Interrupt execution and display a modal message by using the MessageBox.Show method in the System.Windows.Forms namespace. (Remove this code after you complete the debugging process.)
- Raise events for informational messages, warnings, and errors. The FireInformation, FireWarning, and FireError methods display the event description in the Visual Studio Output window. However, the FireProgress method, the Console.Write method, and Console.WriteLine method do not display any information in the Output window. Messages from the FireProgress event appear on the Progress tab of SSIS Designer. For more information, see Raising Events in the Script Component.
- Log events or user-defined messages to enabled logging providers. For more information, see Logging in the Script Component.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but I have an idea like to share

As it's been answered by Guilherme, I can add something might be useful, if your foreach is based on a SQL query, you can add a `ROW_NNUMBER()` to it and assign it to a variable, inside the script task you can compare the value of this variable and break the task on any row you want.

```
if (Dts.Variables["Your_Variable"].Value.ToString() == "4") {
    Console.WriteLine("Break");
}
```

At least you can stop iterating any place in the loop, rather than the first iteration.